# Java code to extract string between two slashes

Tags: java, string, split

I want to extract text between two slashes followed by one slash,
Ex:  `\\stackoverflow\something`

I want to extract `stackoverflow` from that string, how will I do so?

Comment: Yes it is "two slashes followed by one slash" i want text between them.

Answer (score 2):

Very self explanatory. We have a string and we have an array. We split the array by the "\" slashes and we are given parts. The part of index "1" contains our desired word "stackoverflow" Use double slashes since the slashes have to be escaped in Java

```
    String sentence = "\\\\stackoverflow\\something";

    String [] parts = sentence.split("\\\\");

    System.out.println(parts[2]);
```

[image]

Comment: But i will explian the scenario ,i will read string from excel sheet it is like "\\stackoverflow\something\something " .ineed to extract string between two slashes(\\) followed by one slash(\).

Comment: @Thejesh I ran the above code with some excel parsing, it should do what you want. Replace the `String sentence` with your Excel String source. You don't need to escape backslashes in that instance, only with the `split()` method.

Comment: @ThejeshDhanda if it works, please close the question and select an answer, otherwise you can leave it open